# How do I assign values to a class using its parameters? - Basic

Tags: class, actionscript-3, object, parameters, actionscript

so I'm using flash punk to work on a game and i've created a base class that contains the characters stats based on the type of character the player chooses. this is what that class looks like so far.

```
public class Stats extends Entity
{
        public var ATK:Number;
        public var ARM:Number;
        public var SPD:Number;
        public var WIS:Number;
        public var CRG:Number;
        public var STM:Number;

    public function Stats(ATK:Number=0, ARM:Number=0, SPD:Number=0, WIS:Number=0, CRG:Number=0, STM:Number=0)
    {

    }
    override public function update():void 
    {
        super.update();

    }
}
```

and in another class when a button is clicked i would like it to make a new stats class with the parameters (2, 6, 2, 2, 4, 4)
so i do

```
public var SkelStats:Stats = new Stats(2, 6, 2, 2, 4, 4);
```

and then assign that object (SkelStats) to the players boss type varriable. I do this

```
public static var BossType:Stats;
```

and then in the button class under the click function I add

```
Player.BossType = SkelStats; trace(Player.BossType.ATK)
```

and the trace always puts out 0 unless i change the varriable (ATK) in the stats class itself. Why doesn't it change when I enter it in the parameters for the instance of the class?(SkelStats)

Sorry if this is all too confusing, I can answer any questions about my code if anything is unclear. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! All i had to do was store the variables from the constructor with in the class also. apparently constructor defined variables are temporary. So I changed

```
    public var ATK:Number;
    public var ARM:Number;
    public var SPD:Number;
    public var WIS:Number;
    public var CRG:Number;
    public var STM:Number;
```

to this

```
    public var attack:Number;
    public var armour:Number;
    public var speed:Number;
    public var wisdom:Number;
    public var courage:Number;
    public var stamina:Number;
```

and add this

```
    attack  = ATK;
    armour  = ARM;
    speed   = SPD;
    wisdom  = WIS;
    stamina = STM;
    courage = CRG;
```

to this

```
public function Stats(ATK:Number=0, ARM:Number=0, SPD:Number=0, WIS:Number=0, CRG:Number=0, STM:Number=0)
{

}
```

The end class looks like this and works exactly how i wanted it to:

```
public class Stats extends Entity
{
        public var attack:Number;
        public var armour:Number;
        public var speed:Number;
        public var wisdom:Number;
        public var courage:Number;
        public var stamina:Number;

    public function Stats(ATK:Number=0, ARM:Number=0, SPD:Number=0, WIS:Number=0, CRG:Number=0, STM:Number=0)
    {
        attack  = ATK;
        armour  = ARM;
        speed   = SPD;
        wisdom  = WIS;
        stamina = STM;

    }
}
```

Found all these answers here: [AS3 passing constructor parameters as variables in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068325/as3-passing-constructor-parameters-as-variables-in-class)